What's this damaged 3-pin rectangular power connctor on a FLIR thermal camera?
I'm hoping this is a standard-ish connector but I have my doubts.
It's the 12V power line that plugs into the battery or charging dock of a FLIR T335/T365.


Measuring the undamaged part the overall size is 6 mm × 4 mm. Measuring between the pins where the damage should have the least effect gives me 1.1 mm pitch.  Because of the way they're bent, I reckon that's more likely to be 1.27 mm (0.05") than 1 mm.
This is the socket in the battery (from a slight angle to better show the actual connections)


A clear photo of the socket it fits into might help.

@Finbarr I took one; it's black-on-black and doesn't show much so I didn't include it.  Here's a new, deliberately overexposed, shot.

Assuming you're trying to replace it, have you tried asking FLIR? They might be able to send you a replacement power supply. For things like this (i.e. minor accessories to a very expensive product), it's entirely possible they won't even charge you for it.

@Hearth replacement PSUs have been sold in the past, for about £150. Most places are out of stock and the administrative delays of sourcing one from a non-approved supplier are a problem. Plan B is to go straight into the charging base with no connector

@ChrisH Well, emailing the company might land you a part number at the very least, and doesn't cost you anything but a little time.

@Hearth I actually have, but I'm trying all my options in parallel. I've got used to more often than not getting no response at all for technical queries, or an unhelpful one weeks later.  Usually after a tedious webform and sign-up process rather than simply being able to send an email (that's the case here, I'm hoping they'll be more helpful)

FLIR were better than many companies and got me the part number for a replacement power supply/charger kit within a few days (the original being obsolete as well as broken).  While the new one isn't technically discontinued, it's still so old that stock is hard to come by.  Ideally I'd still repair the one I have with a new connector, but for reasons of time I might have to bypass the socket and hard-wire the PSU into the charging base (no running the camera off the mains then)
